# Change color in mvvm

Tags: android, mvvm

In my app i use pattern "mvvm". In my viewModel class i got some float in method:

```
@Bindable
    public String getOneHourPercentChange(){
        float percent = mCurrency.getQuotes().get(mRate.name()).getPercentChange1h();
        String result;

        if(percent>0)
            result = "+" + percent;
        else
            result = "" + percent;

        return result;
    }
```

How to change the text color depending on the value of the variable "percent"? if the percent is less than zero, then red, otherwise green.

Here is my xml code where I use the percent:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/one_hours_value"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@{viewModel.oneHourPercentChange}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/one_hours_label"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Show  your xml code, where you want change color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a separate `BindingAdapter`

```
@BindingAdapter("myColorAttr")
    public static void bindColorAttr(View view, float value) {
        if(valeue >= 0) view.setBackgroundColor(...green...);
        else view.setBackgroundColor(...red...);
}
```

So you will have float value inside your viewModel, and your xml will refer to it like this:

```
app:myColorAttr="@{viewModel.someFloatValue}"
```

Comment: sorry, I was not accurate in question. i need change text color. but i try this code

Comment: you will just need to change body of adapter to change the color of text, also you might change view to textview

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong, but i create method for bind. he return float. in xml this not work. line with attribute app:textColor is not highlighted in white (looks like string)

Comment: are you getting any error during compile time or the app launches? Did you put float value into ObservableField wrapper?

Comment: works for me. just forget make method static. thanks

Comment: enjoy coding! ))

Answer (score 2):

Create `MutableLiveData<Float>` `percent` in ViewModel and then subscribe for change in activity(or fragment) with simple if statment setting color.
In View:

```
@BindView(R.id.one_hours_value) //ButterKnife
TextView hoursValue;
private MainViewModel mainViewModel;

@Override
onCreateView(/..../){
...
initLiveData();
initViewModel();
 ...
}
//setting ViewModel
private void initViewModel() {
    mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MainViewModel.class);
}

private void initLiveData(){
mainViewModel.getPercent().observe(this, () -> {
           // set color here with if/case statement
        });
```

In ViewModel:

```
private MutableLiveData<Float> percent = new MutableLiveData<>();
...
private void setPercent(Float percent){
    this.percent.setValue(percent);
}

public MutableLiveData<Float> getPercent(){
    return percent;
}
//here some method setting percent or maybe in construcor
```

Comment: it's interesting